# When drawing a shape over my texture, OpenGL makes my texture semi-transparent

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, alpha, glkit

### Overview

I'm trying to build a graphic in my game by combining a few images and gradients. I started by using Core Graphics which worked wonderfully, but was abysmally slow. I've now tried to port it over to OpenGL using GLKit and I'm very close, but there's one last issue:

I've already drawn a texture into a triangle on the screen. Now, over the top of it, I'd like to draw a gradient. To draw a gradient, I figured it'd be easiest to just draw a triangle with a black color at two of the vertices and a fully transparent (alpha=0) color on the third. The gradient renders fine by itself, but when it is rendered over the top of the texture, it appears as if the alpha of the texture is also affected and causes the background to show through.

What I want:

[image]

What I get instead:

[image]

I admit that I'm not too familiar with OpenGL or GLKit. I suspect that the texture's alpha at every point on the triangle is (1 - gradient alpha) which would explain why the texture is fully opaque in the corner and why both the texture and gradient seem to have partial transparency in the middle.

Can I accomplish what I want with GLKit? Does it even relate to GLKit and GLKBaseEffect, or am I just doing some funky multi-texturing thing in OpenGL that I can turn off?

### Code Snippets

Render function in my sprite class, for drawing the texture:

```
typedef struct {
    CGPoint geometryVertex;
    CGPoint textureVertex;
} TexturedVertex;

- (void)renderTriangleStrip:(TexturedVertex *)coordinates ofSize:(NSInteger)size {
    self.effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeReplace;
    self.effect.texture2d0.name = self.textureInfo.name;
    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;

    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.transform;

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);

    long offset = (long)coordinates;        
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, textureVertex)));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, size);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
}
```

Render function in my shape class, for drawing the triangle w/gradient:

```
typedef struct {
    CGPoint position;
    GLKVector4 color;
} ColoredVertex;

- (void)renderVertices:(ColoredVertex *)vertices ofSize:(NSInteger)size {
    self.effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeDecal;
    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = NO;

    self.effect.useConstantColor = NO;

    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = self.transform;

    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);

    long offset = (long)vertices;
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ColoredVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(ColoredVertex, position)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ColoredVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(ColoredVertex, color)));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, size);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit**: It seems like glBlendFunc(...) might contain my answer. But I don't understand the different modes. Am I on the right track here?

**Edit**: Still no solution yet, but I've updated my assumptions in the question.

Comment: What are your vertex colors again? Could you list them, please?

Comment: I'd like to be able to make the vertices any color with any alpha, but for the sake of the example above, two are pure black (GLKVector4Make(0, 0, 0, 1.0f)) and the other is fully transparent (GLKVector4Make(0, 0, 0, 0.0f)). I'm used to approaching this problem as if it was a canvas, so drawing semi-transparent pixels on top of already-rendered stuff should affect its alpha. Apparently that isn't the case in OpenGL.

Comment: I assume your aren't really "drawing a triangle on top of a texture" but rather drawing a triangle with that texture and modulated by those vertex colors. That's how one thinks of it in OpenGL terminology. Use white (1, 1, 1, 1) for the third vertex color and everything should be good.

Comment: Doesn't seem like that's it. Setting two vertices to black and the other to white (all fully opaque) resulted in a fully opaque gradient with no visible texture or background. As far as I can tell, the alpha of the texture is being set to (1 - alpha of gradient) at every pixel so using 3 fully opaque vertex colors just shows a fully opaque gradient.

Comment: Ah, you're doing two rendering passes. It would be a lot easier if you set black, black white and render the textured tri in one pass.

Comment: That can't be the full story, though. What if I wanted to draw the gradient a few pixels offset from the texture? Or draw another semi-transparent texture instead of a gradient? I couldn't draw them in the same render pass, could I? I'm really surprised there's not an easy way to draw in multiple passes like painting on a canvas.

Comment: Actually that IS the easy (straightforward and performant) way for what you wanted (for anyone who is familiar with OpenGL/DirectX). With an API like OpenGL, there are many ways to do many things. For example for your "offset drawing" I WOULD suggest a multi-pass render and to render another image instead of a gradient I would have suggested multitexturing and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your problem, so I'll try to restate it as I get it.

1. You draw your checker background
2. You draw an opaque triangle textures with your noisy texture
3. You draw a triangle with a color gradient, which you want to affect the colors underneath it.

I understand that it is pass 3 that causes you problems.

If this is it, what you need to do to obtain your reference image is to draw your gradient triangle using a proper blending mode, and proper vertex colors. In your case, two black colors and one white color.

For you case, the blending would be setup using :

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_SRC_COLOR);
```

This will instruct OpenGL to draw you triangle so that the resulting pixel color is given by `dst = 0 * src + src * dst`, which is `dst = dst * src`.

Comment: Woohoo! You nailed it. Like I said in the comments above, I couldn't figure out the right combination of blend function parameters. Thanks a lot!!